# How to determine type of widget in a qtable cell?

Tags: c++, qt4

I have created a `QTable` with lots of gui elements like `comboBoxes` and `checkBoxes` in various cells. I am able to access these elements by creating pointers to them. What I want to know is, is there any way to know what type of `widget`(`comboBox` or `checkBox`) a cell is having?

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest using `qobject_cast` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast

It works like `dynamic_cast` but is a little better since it can make some Qt specific assumptions (doesn't depend on RTTI).

You can use it like this:

```
if(QPushButton *pb = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(widget)) {
    // it's a "QPushButton", do something with pb here
}
// etc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write following utility functions:

```
bool IsCheckBox(const QWidget *widget)
{
   return dynamic_cast<const QCheckBox*>(widget) != 0;
}
bool IsComboBox(const QWidget *widget)
{
   return dynamic_cast<const QComboBox*>(widget) != 0;
}
```

Or maybe, you can use `typeid` to determine the runtime *type* of the object in the cell.

EDIT:

As @Evan noted in the comment, you can also use [`qobject_cast`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html) to cast the object, instead of `dynamic_cast`. See the examples [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html).

Comment: better to use `qobject_cast`. It is faster, doesn't depend on RTTI and works across library boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QObject::className()` to get the type of the widget.